# String inside double quotes (double quotes included String)

Tags: java

My String is "Please help" including double quotes in a script.

I need Please help excluding double quotes.
Please let me know how i can get Please help from here.

Comment: `string.replaceAll("\"","")` or `string.substring(1,string.length-1)`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for escape characters:

```
"A \" B"
```

Comment: OP wants *excluding double quotes*

Comment: in my case spring itself is double quotes included , i need value inside these quotes